# Windows Explorer - how can I get it to stop randomly choosing how to display folders?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

When I go into a folder, Windows Explorer (in Vista) seems to randomly choose how to display the folder - i.e. whether Icons or Details are shown, the Group By setting etc.

This can happen for folders which I maybe haven't viewed previously in Windows Explorer; for example, it might choose to display it as Music when it doesn't have any music in it.

It can also happen for folders which I have previously viewed in Windows Explorer.
For example, I've just gone into one of my folders, which contains primarily other folders, and it has chosen to Group By Name. Previously, I had chosen to display it with no grouping (i.e. Group By (None)).

Other times, it might still show Details for a folder, but only show the Name column, when I had previously displayed Date modified, Size and Type.

How can I control Windows Explorer to do what I want it to do - which is to always display Details with no grouping for newly shown folders, and remembering old setting for previously shown folders?

Answer (score 3):

See the following article:

[Delete and Reset Windows Vista Folder Views or Folder Types Settings to Default Clean State](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/delete-and-reset-windows-vista-folder-views-or-folder-types-settings-to-default-clean-state/)

> Using Windows Explorer in Windows
>   Vista is sometimes annoying and
>   confusing as the folder views settings
>   and folder types customization is not
>   working consistently. Folder views
>   which determines which view, such as
>   tiles, details, list, small icons,
>   medium icons, large icons or extra
>   large icons, that users is using to
>   browse files and items in Explorer
>   window, while folder types set the
>   template which shows kind of folder
>   and its related commands and buttons
>   in toolbar. However, the
>   implementation in Vista is buggy,
>   messy and abnormal.
>
> The easiest solution all Folder Types
>   and Folder Views mess in Vista is by
>   reset all settings and customizations
>   related to Folder Types and Views to
>   revert back to out-of-the box
>   post-installation defaults. Note that
>   you should try to use Reset Folder in
>   Folder Options (open by clicking
>   Organize -> Folder and Search Options
>   and then go to View tab) before trying
>   registry hack below.
>
> Registry tweak below will delete and
>   reset all folder view and folder type
>   settings to default and clean state by
>   rebuilding the related registry key,
>   so that every start fresh again from
>   scratch. All remembered folder
>   settings in Windows Explorer for view
>   state, window position, sort order,
>   column information, folder type,
>   toolbar toggles, and search result
>   views will be lost, and reset to the
>   original defaults.

Answer (score 2):

**Fix "Vista Unable or Fail to Remember or Save Folder Types / Views Setting Error" by Increasing BagMRU Cache Memory Size**

> 1. Run Registry Editor (regedit).
> 2. Navigate to the following registry key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
> ```
>
> 3. If you can see BagMRU Size value in the right pane, skip this step. If BagMRU Size is not found, right click on a blank space in the right pane, then select New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value. Then, type BagMRU Size as the value name.
> 4. Double click on BagMRU Size key just created, and then enter 10000 (in decimal base) or 2710 (in hexadecimal base) as its value data.
>
> Note that 5000 is the supposedly default settings for BagMRU Size in Vista. You can set any other value you like, taking into account the number of folders you have.

**[Source](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/fix-vista-unable-or-fail-to-remember-or-save-folder-typesviews-setting-error-by-increasing-bagmru-cache-memory-size/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can run this Batch file to perform the necessary registry edits with one click:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("HKCR\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell" "HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell" "HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoom") do (
  for %%b in (Bags BagMRU) do (
    reg delete "%%~a\%%~b" /f
  )
)
:: Additional tweaks
reg add "HKCR\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell" /v FolderType /t REG_SZ /d NotSpecified /f
reg add "HKCR\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell" /v "BagMRU Size" /t REG_DWORD /d 10000 /f 
rundll32 user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer
exit /b 0
```